# XCode 4.2 linker error Library not found -lFlurryAnalytics

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2, flurry

[image]

I am getting this error when trying to build my project.  I have a paid / free version the paid version is working just fine with the same library.  However for some reason the free version is having a hard time with the Flurry Analytics library which is the same file version as the paid app.  I added it by going to Add > Existing Frameworks... Add Other and browsed to the library in the paid apps folder.  I am not sure what else to try I have made sure the project settings between paid and free version are identical, I have tried coping that file locally, I have googled and googled and am coming up short.

using Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if library is added in TARGETS -> Link Binary With Libraries. Mostly it will be there but wrong version. If you change the iOS version you should change binary as well.
e.g. libz.1.dylib is in iOS7 link binary.
But if you change to iOS9.1 you have to delete libz.1.dylib and add one from iOS9.1 libz.1.tbd

Answer (score 1):

it's likely not in the list of ld's search paths. either qualify the path or add its parent to the list of directories for ld to search.

Comment: I tried that and that didn't work.  I also tried, just coping the library locally and then adding the framework back in and that didn't work either

Comment: @odyth hmm... i would carefully check for differences in the transcripts of the two apps for the linking stage (the photo in your OP), as well as the build settings relevant to linking and library directories (discovery can vary, depending on how you have built your project and how you define your build settings).

Comment: Best answer yet. Easiest solution IMHO: delete the old path from the Xcode project and drag in the libraries (in this case Flurry) again.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue recently: I had this error when updating a project from an older version of React Native to a newer one. To resolve the issue like user2661518 suggested you may have to search a little. I selected my project in the Project Navigator, selected my Target, and under Build Phases opened up the Link Binary With Libraries option. I had to remove the library that was throwing the error by selecting it and clicking the "-" icon, and then re-added it by clicking the "+" icon and selecting it (mine was under Pods).

Answer (score 0):

We just had a project fail to build after upgrading to Xcode 4.2.  In our case the error was:

```
ld: library not found for -lz.1.2.3
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

It turns out that this particular SDK library changed versions, and the file we were pointing to is no longer included in the latest distribution.

To fix it, I clicked on the libz.1.2.3.dylib entry in the Xcode Project Navigator pane.  (It was highlighted in a red font because its path was incorrect.)  Next, in the Xcode Utilities pane, in the File Inspector tab, I clicked on the "Choose File" icon beneath the Location listbox which is set to "Relative to SDK".  I navigated to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/ and found that libz.1.2.3.dylib didn't exist, so I chose the latest version libz.1.2.5.dylib.