# I am getting error when i am building a project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Following error is shown while building the project in Xcode

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group
: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please give more details on the error. It is hard to find out what the issue is with the detail you gave

Comment: Known error (you could search for it) that could have various reasons (and so fixes). It's missing all the import error message that indicates the real reasons.

Comment: i am getting a this error when i build my project.so tell how to resolve this issue

Comment: Goto View->Navigators->Show Report Navigator. Select the latest build and see what error you are getting

Comment: Look at that screen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885374/xcode-4-2-linker-error-library-not-found-lflurryanalytics It show the important information that you need to share with us if you want some help. Without them, it's PURE guess.

Comment: Showing Recent Issues
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: when i import my project .then there were showing on warning update your settings . i clicked and updated settings then i get this issue.

Comment: you must have some other description in the error block. check that. It should give you more descriptive reason of an error. If not, plz check for duplicate files in build phases. If any, remove it. Check for red mark files and remove it. clean - build project and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

`Go to ProjectTraget->BuidPhase->Compile Source And check duplicate .h File .If Duplicate File Found then Remove it.and try again to Build`.